# In Discord, how can I move a channel to outside 'text channels'?

Tags: discord

I have 2 default categories in my Discord server: text channels and voice channels. But some channels are in neither. How can I create a new channel in neither category or better, move a text channel to the no category area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag a channel to the null space **above** the text channel to move it outside of the category.

You will first have to create it inside a category, but after that, it can be moved out.

Alterantively you can also create a new category, give it a name, and drag channels to that location. You can drag this category above the other one to rearrange it too.

[image]

Comment: The drag and drop to null does not work for me :(

Comment: Do you use the desktop app or website? I tested this in the app.

Comment: Just tested, it works in the browser too, but you must be careful to drag at the bar itself, not the text.

Comment: I use the app :(. But there is no bar in the null category

Comment: You hover the bar to the right of the word and drag to above until a green line appears. I've now edited the answer and provided an animation.

Comment: Tricky but works